# Display scrollbar inside a fixed position element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have elements (`.block`) inside a div (`#block_list`). The parent of `#block_list` is another div (`#block_list-wrapper`) which has a fixed position. Now since the `#block_list-wrapper` has fixed position, some of the elements of the `#block_list` are not displayed. I would like to display them using a scrollbar.

html:

```
<div id="block_list-wrapper">
    <div id="handle-wrapper">
        <div id="handle">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="block_list">
        <div class="one_column_block-1 block">
            <img src="static/image/one_column_block-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="one_column_block-2 block">
            <img src="static/image/one_column_block-2.png">
        </div>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <div class="one_column_block-1 block">
            <img src="static/image/four_column_block-3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code demo at [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/OypKvw?editors=001)

I tried adding `overflow: scroll` like so,

```
#block_list-wrapper #block_list {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

but it didn't help either.

How can I show scroll bar to display all the elements (`.block`) inside the `#block_list`?

Comment: try with `slimScroll`.

Comment: you need to add a fixed height in order to have any kind of scolling on a element. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQpVgW

Comment: @StefanPerju Hey, glad to meet Romanians here!! :D

Comment: @IonicăBizău We're everywhere, dude. :D

Comment: @StefanPerju Haha, good point. Yes we are, even on SO! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line of code to set the height of the element:

```
$("#block_list").css("height", $(window).height())
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meWNGL)

Another solution would be, obviously, to do this with CSS, like the other answers say.

Answer (score 1):

Add height 100% to both your block_list and block_list-wrapper and then add overflow : scroll to block_list.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a height specified. You can, specify height to the container in one of the following ways:

1. Specify `height: 100vh` to your `#block_list-wrapper #block_list`, or
2. Specify `height: 100vh` to your `#block_list-wrapper` and then a `height:100%` to your `#block_list-wrapper #block_list`.

Your codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBgpo

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a fixed height for the block_list element. You can use the vh property and set `heigth: 100vh`.

An updated CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQpVgW)

Answer (score 0):

Give height to the element so that you could get the scroller on `div`.
The following link code works fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/LLrkfvhf/